# Hive Issue with Update

Tags: hadoop, transactions, hive

I am trying to create a table that will allow for updates.  I have looked at several documents on how to configure this.  We are using HDP 2.2.4.5 and Hive 0.14.

Here are the configurations i have set.  I run these in the command client for hive.

```
hive> set hive.support.concurrency;
hive.support.concurrency=true
hive> set hive.enforce.bucketing;
hive.enforce.bucketing=true
hive> set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode;
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
hive> set hive.txn.manager;
hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager
hive> set hive.compactor.initiator.on;
hive.compactor.initiator.on=true
hive> set hive.compactor.worker.threads;
hive.compactor.worker.threads=1
```

Here is the create statement for my table:

```
CREATE TABLE bt_xda_zgrp_sch_stg_update_3(
`xda_zgrp_id` int,
`day_of_wk_ind` int,
`max_dlvry_qty` int,
`last_upd_user_id` string,
`last_upd_ts` timestamp)
clustered by (xda_zgrp_id) into 9 buckets 
stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
```

Please let me know if you see any issues or have any advice.

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that i was running a command (like "use db_name")before setting the Txn.manager.  This caused the txn.manager to be set initialized and couldnt be reset until a new session was opened.  If i set this property before I do anything else it will work.  Please find a more detailed answer here:

http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/help-with-hive-update/

Answer (score 0):

From your Table Create command, its clear that you are creating a bucketed table.

**"Hive Update" Cannot be performed on Bucketed tables.**

Please find the limitations of Hive Update from the [official Hive Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update)

Hope this helps :)